# Undecorated Alert will not close when requested

Tags: javafx, alert

I have a simple undecorated `Alert` that I am trying to display while a long-running task is being completed in the background.

However, when the task is finished, I want to close the alert.  I can not, however, get the alert to close by calling either `close()` or `hide()`.

This MCVE does not include the background `Task`, but even this refuses to close the alert:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class AlertClosing extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Alert simpleAlert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.NONE);

        simpleAlert.setContentText("Testing");
        simpleAlert.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

        simpleAlert.show();

        // None of these seem to have any effect.
        simpleAlert.close();
        simpleAlert.hide();
        Platform.runLater(simpleAlert::close);
    }
}
```

I have found a few other answers here that deal with `Alert` and `Dialog` panes that have a cancel button, but my `Alert` has no buttons at all; it's simply meant to display a message while the background task is running.

Per the JavaDocs on `Dialog` closing rules:

> JavaFX dialogs can only be closed 'abnormally' (as defined above) in
>   two situations:
>
> - When the dialog only has one button, or
> - When the dialog has multiple buttons, as long as one of them meets    one of the following requirements:
>
>   - The button has a ButtonType whose ButtonBar.ButtonData is of type       ButtonBar.ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE.
>   - The button has a ButtonType whose ButtonBar.ButtonData returns true    when ButtonBar.ButtonData.isCancelButton() is called.
>
> In all other situations, the dialog will refuse to respond to all
>   close requests, remaining open until the user clicks on one of the
>   available buttons in the DialogPane area of the dialog.

So this too suggests that a simple `close()` request should be honored since there are no qualifying buttons in an `Alert(AlertStyle.NONE)`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No according to the javadoc not honoring the close request: There's neither one nor multiple buttons.

You can assign one `ButtonType` as result make the `Alert` close properly.

```
Alert simpleAlert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.NONE);

simpleAlert.setContentText("Testing");
simpleAlert.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

simpleAlert.show();

new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    }
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        simpleAlert.setResult(ButtonType.CANCEL);
        simpleAlert.close();
    });
}).start();
```